# How to deferred response in router?

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I want to gather data from multi tables with sequelize orm. this is my code

```
var recs = [];

models.Data.findAll({
    where: {
        //exchange_id: req.params.exchangeId
        exchange_id: 7
    }
})
.then(function (data) {
    var rec = {};

    data.forEach(function (item, i) {
        console.log('\n data id is ', data[i].id);

        models.ExchangeTable.findOne({
            data_id: data[i].id
        }).then(function (exchangeTable) {
            models.Country_Money.findOne({
                id: exchangeTable.country_money_id
            }).then(function (countryMoney) {
                rec.countryMoneyId = countryMoney.id;
                rec.data = data[i];
            });
        });
    });

    recs.push(rec);
    res.json(recs);
});
```

and the output is:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "sell", "buy", "exchange_id", "createdAt", "up
datedAt" FROM "Data" AS "Data" WHERE "Data"."exchange_id" = 7;

 data id is  185

 data id is  186
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "data_id", "country_money_id", "createdAt", "u
pdatedAt" FROM "ExchangeTables" AS "ExchangeTable" LIMIT 1;
GET /ServiceProviders/Exchange/table/5 200 60.349 ms - 4
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "data_id", "country_money_id", "createdAt", "u
pdatedAt" FROM "ExchangeTables" AS "ExchangeTable" LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "Country_id", "Money_id" FROM "Country_Money"
AS "Country_Money" LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "Country_id", "Money_id" FROM "Country_Money"
AS "Country_Money" LIMIT 1;
```

my problem is I don't know how use deferred in loop block due to give the `where` condition of `Country_Money` model the expected value that must be provided in `Data` model.

Please tell me, How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting for the promises created within `forEach` to complete before sending the response with `res#json`. Although the database lookups may take some time they are being performed asynchronously and so execution of the code *after* the `forEach` is not being made to wait for their completion. In order to make them *wait* we can trade in the `forEach` for mapping each of the promises within the iterator to a promise:

```
var promises = data.map(function (item, i) {
    console.log('\n data id is ', data[i].id);

    // We must return a value here
    return models
        .ExchangeTable
        .findOne({data_id: data[i].id})
        .then(function (exchangeTable) {

            // Every promise we create must be returned so that
            // its parent waits for it to resolve before giving
            // control to the next `then`
            return models
                .Country_Money
                .findOne({id: exchangeTable.country_money_id})
                .then(function (countryMoney) {

                    // Return an object literal with the data we want
                    // instead of affecting an external store.
                    // This will be the final value for an iteration
                    // and available as a member of the array result of `Promise.all`
                    return {
                        countryMoneyId: countryMoney.id,
                        data: data[i]
                    };
                });
            });
        });
```

This will produce an array of promises that can be handed to [`Promise#all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Finally, the code that depends on each of these promises must be placed within a `then` after `Promise#all`.

```
return Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(function (recs) {
        // Here we receive the final result of each
        // promise returned within `data.map` as an array
        res.json(recs);
    });
```

Using this approach we no longer need to maintain `var recs = [];` or `var rec = {};`. Take a look at the purpose and behaviour of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for why this is.

Comment: This example is using native Promises.

Comment: Thanks @sdgluck it works as a charm, but is there any way to solve these kind of problems in linear solution rather than callback-based, I mean use `for` or `while`  loop?